# Google Sheets - Count Unique Values of Importrange Data between Given Dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with a Name Column and corresponding Date column. I'm attempting to count the number of times unique Names appear for a specific Date range. The data is in a separate spreadsheet, so I'm using importrange in the formulas.

I created a sample spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTDTrU3Mueds_xBX7Q9GXTMhyaMomzsT7dg7WXeUtHs/edit?usp=sharing) - we can pretend that the "Data" tab is on a separate spreadsheet file. I have the below formula so far but I'm not sure how to tell it to only count the unique Name values between the Dates in cells B2 and C2.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VHR-T9bo0E1KH4yZp-9wTW6JGjKh4b3qMdm99MP_vB8/edit#gid=0","Data!A:B"),"Select Count(Col1) where Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 <= date '"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' Label Count(Col1) ''")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a google sheets function called =COUNTUNIQUE()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should do it:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1VHR-T9bo0E1KH4yZp-9wTW6JGjKh4b3qMdm99MP_vB8","Data!A2:B"),"select Col1 where Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2<= date '"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0))
```